# Receive a message in ZeroMQ without predefining the buffer in C#

Tags: c#, performance, zeromq

Currently when receiving a binary message in ZMQ I have to perform the following:

```
int maxMessageSize = 1024*500*16*                            
var buffer = new byte[maxMessageSize];
var messageLength = socket.Receive(buffer);
var message = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, messageLength).ToArray();
```

This has a major issue:
 I have to know in advance the max message size, which i have no idea of. messages can be anywhere from 1KB to 20MB of size. any way to just receive the message entirely without predefined the buffer size and then trimming it into an array?

Comment: from where did you get that code? zermq messages are delimited by length, why do you need to know the length ahead of time?

Answer (score 0):

You can code the sender to send the message in two parts.

The first part being the buffer size (`int`) can be sent with **`socket.SendMore()`**.

The second part the buffer itself with the regular **`socket.Send()`**.

Set the **`maxMessageSize`** to the first **`socket.Receive()`** and then `socket.Receive()` again, with the correct buffer size.